# What URL do I return if upload directory not within site

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm writing my own UploadHandler for the Blueimp Jquery file upload plugin, and I have to return a url of the uploaded file. However, my application uploads to a directory outside of the site for use elsewhere.

The documentation shows the return JASOn entry to be

```
{"files": [
 {
"name": "picture1.jpg",
"size": 902604,
"url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
"thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg",
"deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
"deleteType": "DELETE"
 },
 {
"name": "picture2.jpg",
"size": 841946,
"url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
"thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture2.jpg",
"deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
"deleteType": "DELETE"
 }
]}
```

however in my case the URL isn't within the site, it's a directory outside of the root directory.

What should I return? This goes for the delete processing too.

Regards
Pete

Comment: If you don't know how could we possibly know? We have no idea where you send it or how it gets handled there. Maybe there's something missing in this question?

Comment: I thought the developer responded to these questions as per the gitHub entry.

Comment: Nobody can respond without making this a much more descriptice question

Comment: I've included the documented return jason object that needs to be returned. My directory isn't part of my site.

Comment: If the url isn't returned that is a problem with where you are uploading to...not the plugin. Check the documentation of  api you are sending it to. Seems rather improbable that it goes into a black hole with no response. What does response look like that api returns? Can inspect it in browser dev tools network tab

Comment: My point is that it returns a link to the uploaded file winin m the site. If I upload it to a directory outside my site, what type of link should I return.

Comment: This really makes no sense... if it only exists at one url...what other url could you use?

Comment: I upload files to a directory that is outside of the site. So I cannot return a URL to it. That is what I am asking, what would I return? Where I upload it to is outside the control of the plugin, but it seems to imply that it needs to be within the site. I suppose I could upload the files to a site directory, then move them later.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided that it might be best to upload the files to a directory within the site then move that to the external directory as a workaround.

Regards
Pete